# There are two sites i am trying to find if they have API/JSON back ends

Tags: json, web-scraping

HI all i have been working on a big project and i need to know if two sites i am working from has api/json backend i can get there data from , i have used f12 and then network and i cant seem to find anything but i have been looking all day so i might have missed something

https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures

https://hobartairport.com.au/flights/

Thanks for all your helps guys

Comment: All data you need is on Network tab. Open [1st link](https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures), go to Network tab, choose XHR filter, select any city in "TO/FROM CITY" dropdown on the page, then again change selection to initial "-- SELECT CITY", check logged request, there you can find [URL](https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flightsearch&flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=) which actually are the HTML data which output in the table.

Comment: Regarding [2nd link](https://hobartairport.com.au/flights/), seems the page doesn't use AJAX, so all data is located in initially loaded page HTML content, also you may try to check if any data is received when you press "VIEW MORE FLIGHT DATA" button.

Comment: ok so i think i am seeing it how would i go about using that with python and getting hte data

Comment: I would start [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+parse+html)

Comment: arrr ok so i cant just use something like json :(